# ViewPagerIndicator tabs to become ActionBarSherlock spinner in landscape

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, viewpagerindicator

I'm using both ViewPagerIndicator and ActionBarSherlock in my projects.

Is there an easy way to make ViewPagerIndicator tabs become a spinner in ActionBarSherlock when the device is rotated to landscape? You know, so as to make more room available for the rest of content.

Do I have to do all the work manually capturing the event `@onConfigurationChanged`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is really what you want, rather than using `ViewPagerIndicator`, you should be using tabs in the action bar. Those will automatically convert to a drop-down list in the action bar in different circumstances.  Here is a sample project demonstrating tying `ViewPager` to action bar tabs: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/TabPager

Note, though, that there is a bug in Android, reproduced in ActionBarSherlock for compatibility, that will mean that swipe events in the `ViewPager` will not be reflected in the action bar when in drop-down list mode.

If you *really* want to use ViewPagerIndicator instead of action bar tabs, not only are you on your own, but you will suffer from the same bug that I mentioned in the previous paragraph.

Personally, I recommend using tabs (whether `PagerTabStrip` or ViewPagerIndicator) in all cases, rather than switching back and forth.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is that I want to be able to swype horizontally to change tabs. Is this doable using just ActionBarSherlock tabs? Tab example in ABS Showcase demo app doesn't do this. This is why I'm using ViewPagerIndicator tabs.

Comment: @PabloM.: "The thing is that I want to be able to swype horizontally to change tabs. Is this doable using just ActionBarSherlock tabs?" -- yes, when they are tabs, not in the drop-down list. The project that I linked to above demonstrates this.

Comment: I'll take a look. This way, I see no point in using VPI just for tabs if using ABS, right?. Thank you.

Comment: Btw, just bought my warescription :)

Comment: @PabloM.: "This way, I see no point in using VPI just for tabs if using ABS, right?" -- *if* you want the "convert to drop-down list" feature, yes. Personally, I really dislike that, and so I would be using the built-in `PagerTabStrip` or VPI to avoid it. Also, the bug I mentioned in the answer is annoying and may cause users to think your app is broken. "Btw, just bought my warescription :)" -- many thanks!